# As a profession, what is User Experience?

Tags: definition

I'm writing an article and I have hit this wall (I did before, but forgot about it). Basically, **I need to explain what is User Experience** as a profession or corpus of knowledge.

I don't mean the usual UX definitions, where UX is a *"perception"*. I mean, how can we define UX work conceptually?

Some ideas I have are:

- A discipline
- A set of techniques or methodologies
- A concept
- A framework
- A science
- Something else, including a combination of any of the above

Personally, I tend to go along the line of *"scientific multidisciplinary approach"* which I consider an elegant way to say a lot and nothing at the same time, but what is it exactly?

Comment: For those who downvote, could you at least explain the reason? I don't see anything wrong with this question

Comment: I agree, we are here to help out each other... this question may very well not be suitable, but by giving a feedback OP can improve his question.

Comment: yes @HoomanBahreini, you're correct. Now, there are 2 possible scenarios: there's no agreement on this, or there is an agreement on something (which is what I'd like to know). Either way, this is NOT a "primarily opinion based question". either there's an answer or there is not. Anyways, for me this is like the quintessencial question in UX **(what is UX?!?!?!?)** , but well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't mean the usual UX definitions, where UX is a "perception".

In my opinion, this is confusing, because you are asking about definition of **UX**, but then you don't want the definition of **UX**!

---

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience):

> User Experience (UX) is a person's emotions and attitudes about
>   using a particular product, system or service

So UX, is the **perception** of user from the system... it is not a *Profession*, *Discipline*, *Technique*  or *Framework*...

I think what you are looking for is **User Experience Design (UXD)**, again according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design):

> **User experience design** (UXD, UED, or XD) is the process of
>   manipulating user behavior through usability, accessibility, and
>   desirability provided in the interaction with a product. User
>   experience design encompasses traditional human–computer interaction
>   (HCI) design and extends it by addressing all aspects of a product or
>   service as perceived by users. **Experience design (XD) is the practice of designing products, processes, services...**

I think the last sentence is what you are looking for, **UXD** is the *practice of designing systems*.

Sometimes we loosely use the term *User Experience* instead of *User Experience Design*... but we need to be careful with our terminology when defining these fundamental terms.

Comment: I think the UXD solution is the most suitable for my situation. Thank you :) However, and just as a personal comment,  I find extremely weird that something that requires multiple scientific methods and methodologies is defined randomly by pure subjectivity.

Comment: @Devin That's because UXD is a misleading term. The experience of a user can't simply be designed, not even with all the scientific knowledge we can currently have.
It is what the description says: It is about trying to manipulate the experience a user has. 
Though it can certainly help, it doesn't "require" scientific methods and methodologies to manipulate that. The possibility exists that one could reach the same or better results without them. Science is about knowledge, not about doing the right or wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, UX is a way of thinking. Putting yourself in the user's shoes in order to understand them, and then using the resources at your disposal to improve the user's experience in terms of removing pain points, making things easier, giving the right information that they need, etc.

Comment: Yes, being the person who thinks about the product from the users point of view.